# Why does C use FILE for stdin/stdout streams as well as file operations?

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have recently looked into files and input/output in C and quickly figured out that C uses a `typedef`ed structure known as `FILE` which is commonly represented as a pointer to a structure.
This structure contains data about input and output so lower level parts of the operating system and kernel can easily manage input and output on a system, for example the size of the data being inputted, the type of data etc.
Basically is it purposefully made abstract since the way it works is very low level.

I also know that something like `FILE* x` is commonly used by C programmers to represent input and output streams. C also allows `FILE` to commonly be used to point to a file.

Why does C allow programmers to use `FILE` to represent files as well as input/output streams? To me this sounds very confusing as well as this the keyword `FILE` is literally called `FILE` and i would think it would often confuse new programmers into thinking it is used to ONLY point to files.

So why is `FILE` used for both files and input/output?

Comment: Because on Unix "everything is file" and C was created specially for this OS

Comment: *Basically is it purposefully made abstract...* Right.  It's an abstract I/O stream.  The name `FILE` is somewhat of a misnomer.  You can use a `FILE *` to represent i/o to a file, a device, a network stream, or even an in-memory string.

Comment: @SteveSummit so bascially ```FILE``` can be used to represent any input/output device on a computer? since the structure that ```FILE``` is linked too accounts for all input/output devices?

Comment: @programme3219873 Originally, a `FILE *` was a "handle" for a buffering scheme on top of a Unix *file descriptor*.  And it was actually the Unix file descriptor that referred to data structure(s) that could "account for all input/output devices".  And as far as I know that's typically still how it's implemented today, although it can have its own level of indirection to handle different "devices".  (Typically, the only level of indirection at the `FILE *` level is between i/o to Unix file descriptors, versus i/o to strings.)

Comment: @programme3219873: A `FILE` represents a *stream of bytes*, not a device.  A stream of bytes is a stream of bytes, whether the source or destination of that stream is a file or a printer or a network stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `FILE` is misnamed, it doesn't represent files.  It represents something that can be read from and written to.  That reading from and writing to can be done in single character sizes (streams) or bulk (blocks).

So if you want keyboard input, why not read from the keyboard buffer?  If you want to send a web request, why not write one to the outbound network buffer?  What would you use to do that?

Once the designers of UNIX and C realized that the core common feature set of many items was the ability to read and write, they reused the pattern for many things that people don't consider files.  This is the motivation behind the UNIX "everything is a file" mantra.  Directories are files, containing the names and locations of other files.  Disks are files, expecting writes that follow filesystem layout constraints.  Screens are files, expecting terminal control codes and text.

And what happened to files, the start of this powerful idea?  They're still there, but the `FILE` construct in C is more of an ID in the kernel for a thing that can be possibly read or written from, and isn't guaranteed to back to the regular notion of a file on disk.

Comment: The only problem with renaming it, is that we don't really know what it should be named.  Stream implies how to use it, and many `FILE` handles are access using block based transfer.

Comment: amazing answer thank you

Comment: Re "* Stream implies how to use it*", which is why it's a good name. handles are access using block based transfer. /// Re "*and many FILE handles are access using block based transfer.*", Out of millions of streams, I've never worked with such a stream, so saying "many" is a huge exaggeration. And the point is completely wrong anyway. Streams don't imply bytes. Streams is very often used for things other than bytes (video frames, water, etc). The key aspect is that it's a sequence of possibly indeterminate length.

Comment: Streams imply ordered reading.  File handles can do more.  They can read based off of offsets.  They can reset back to the beginning.  Stream is not a bad name, except it was already used in a narrower context.

Answer (score 7):

Despite its name, `FILE` has nothing to do with files. For example, you can't rename using a `FILE`. You can't delete using a `FILE`.

`FILE` always represents a stream. It's of no relevance whether this stream is associated with a plain file, a pipe or a socket.

Comment: so does this mean that ```FILE``` is just a object type that can be used to represent any input/output device on a computer? since the structure that ```FILE``` is linked too accounts for all input/output devices?

Comment: No, it's used to represent a stream. It has nothing to do with devices either.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "stream"?

Comment: It's not actually a stream, more like a possibly readable / possibly writable identifier.  All block devices are accessed through files too, and streams imply a character device.

Comment: Re "*what exactly do you mean by "stream"?*", "a stream is a source or sink of data, usually individual bytes or characters." [Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing))

Answer (score 1):

On Linux systems,  you can study the source code of [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). It is open source code.

a `FILE`  is then defined as a pointer to some `struct` containing an open file descriptor number, some buffer, etc...

The short name `FILE`  is historical. Invented at a time where a Unix computer had less than 256 kilobytes of memory, and rotating hard disks of a few megabytes. Read wikipedia on [History of Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix).

Answer (score 1):

In many systems (like Linux) (amost) everything is a file. Terminal, network card, random number generator, device tree and much more. Stream (or file) is a very good abstraction for almost anything :)